# How to split text file based on number of space delimiters - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, delimiter

First time asking a question here so please let me know if more information is needed.

Here is an example of the data I am trying to parse into multiple rows:
0 0 159 190 145 20 0 1 159 166 127 21 0 2 159 144 111 22 0 3 166 175 126 19 0 4 168 188 132 17 0 5 169 191 133 18 0 6 168 191 134 18

The first 6 values should be returned in a single row, then the next 6 in a second row, and so on.

I have a XYZRGB point cloud file saved in TXT format with all data in a single row. Each field (x,y,z,r,g,b) is separated by a space. The entire point cloud text file is saved in a single text line. I need to split this file into multiple lines at every 6 space delimiters. I can not use a character count as the split point due to the varied number of characters in each field. I am currently trying this in Notepad++ but I can use a variety of programs.

Thanks in advance for any insight that can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using notepad++, press ctrl+h or bring up the search>replace window.

In the 'find what' text box enter `^((?:\S+\s+){6})`

and in the 'replace with' text box enter `\1\n`

Make sure the search mode is set to 'Regular Expression' and then hit 'Replace All'

It will find six occurrences of continuous non-space characters followed by continuous space characters and replace it with that plus a line feed character.

Using this method, the example you provided:

```
0 0 159 190 145 20 0 1 159 166 127 21 0 2 159 144 111 22 0 3 166 175 126 19 0 4 168 188 132 17 0 5 169 191 133 18 0 6 168 191 134 18
```

becomes:

```
0 0 159 190 145 20 
0 1 159 166 127 21 
0 2 159 144 111 22 
0 3 166 175 126 19 
0 4 168 188 132 17 
0 5 169 191 133 18 
0 6 168 191 134 18
```

I'm sorry I can't suggest any alternative to those delightful earwax colours!